# How to mention that I can't cover all the projects I've done because of page limit in my internship report?

Tags: internship

This is the first time I have to remove projects and shorten explanation to fit into the required number of pages. At the begining of the dissertation I talk a bit about all the projects I have done.

How can I mention the fact that don't have enough space in an indirect way? My tutor said it's not a good idea to say it straighforward, why?

Comment: Your thesis has a maximum page count? That seems odd. And, what level is this thesis?

Comment: @Buffy this is a very common thing in Germany, many universities have page restrictions for Bachelors and Masters, in some disciplines (and depending on the supervisor), there might even be a page limit for PhD theses.

Comment: It's not really a thesis, it's a dissertation covering what I did during the first year in my internship. I'm in the first year of a master degree in France.

Comment: I'd give a short overview about all projects and their main conclusions and then describe only one (the most interesting) project in more detail. But consider first if you can streamline your writing even more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'd seek advice from someone beyond your "tutor". Or, at least, learn why they advise against it.

But a simple way to imply that you have done more than you report is to start out with something like "The most important projects I've done this year are ...". Or possibly "Among the projects I've undertaken this year, the most significant are..."

It is enough to give the idea if you really can't mention details. If oral presentation is part of your process you will probably be asked about the others. Have something ready to say.

I'm guessing that the purpose of the report is to give people a quick way to verify that you are on track. Give them that assurance. The rest is probably unnecessary.